# QQIS composer: Using bold and normal text styling in a label at the same time?

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer

I am writing text explanations for map symbols and need to write three lines for each symbol -  basically explaining the same thing in three different languages.

I'd like to bold the main language - but when I select bold from the composer 'font' menu, it bolds all three lines - not just the one I've highlighted.

Could it be there is no way to mix stylings, font sizes and so on in a single composer label? It would be very handy option if its possible to have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the current version of QGIS (1.8) you will have to have three different label objects under each other.  You can group the label items so that you can move them around as a block.

However in the latest dev version there is a new HTML labels feature that you could use to do this.

```
<h1>mmmm HTML label</h1>
<b>Some bold text</b>
<br><br>
<i>Some other text</i>
<p style="color:blue"><i>Some blue text</i></p>
```

[image]

Comment: All the labels I group together seem to automatically ungroup after I close QGIS - would it be possible the have option to make the grouppings stick until specifically ungrouped?

--

HTML labeling sounds nice to have Ill definitely learn to use it later - but I think having "Word-style" highlight+click editing option would be both easier and faster to use for the average user.

Thanks!

Comment: The editing tools are planned just not implemented yet.